# An apparent contradiction in the simple Lie algebra $E_8$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

The following is the Dynkin diagram for simple Lie algebra $E_8$

[image]

My question is the following:
 It is clear that $e_i+e_j$ for $i \neq j$ is a positive  root. Let $\alpha _8$ be the fundamental positive root $-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^8e_i$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{8}e_i+\alpha_8=-\alpha_8$ which shows that $-\alpha_8$ is a positive root. This is a contradiction. Where did I go wrong? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why is it clear that $e_1+e_8$ is a positive root?

Comment: its not clear to me now. I thought that it is clear but in fact it may not be a positive root!. But surely $e_1+e_7$ is a positive root

Comment: @dulalnarugopal setting aside whether $e_1+e_8$ is a positive root (it may be, I don't recall at the moment), I don't see why what you wrote is a contradiction. It is clear that $\sum_{i=1}^8e_i=-2\alpha_8$ is NOT a root.